# Disable domain IP caching

Tags: caching, dns

I have have few projects that I'm holding on one of my VPS from DigitalOcean. In order to keep them up even my VPS may come down, I bought another VPS from DigitalOcean with idea to sync the projects on both server, so if the main goes down the second will take the lead.

So I set a Cronjob, on the second server, that is checking the projects state on the main, and in case the response is negative, using the DigitalOcean API I change the domain A record to to direct to the second server, until the problem on the main server is not fixed.

I was afraid that the IP propagation will take too much time, but it seems to do it very fast.
Instead there is another problem. It seems the computer is caching the IP address, so it still direct to the main server.
I tested this with few computers and with service like HideMyAss.

Question: Is there a way I can tell from my server to the client that the IP is changed or to not cache my IP?

Thank you

Comment: The solution here is to use a real load balancer. You can't force DNS entries to be changed on clients all over the world. What you're asking is unfeasible.